# Armature Rig Legs Scale and Move Strange when using Master Bone?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

So I made this simple rig and when I try to scale or move it using a master bone, I notice my legs don't move properly.

Here's my blender file
https://pasteall.org/blend/5d716f5e7b424fdb9d03e02578af1a44

Here's the original position
[image]

Then I try a simple Scale and notice the hips move in an outwards direction? instead of straight up

[image]

Then if I try to use G to move it this happens. Why are the legs bending and not maintaining the straight position?

[image]

Update: Realized my IK Bones aren't moving with my master bone, however, I don't know what parent mode I have to set for the IK bones to move with the master bone?

Comment: for your second problem: the lowerlegs have IKs that make them stick to their controller. For your first problem please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: my files in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The lowerlegs have IKs that make them stick to their controller, you're supposed to parent the controller to the master bone if you want to avoid that, and that's the goal of a master bone.
- When you'll have parented the first problem won't happen anymore. It currently happens because the controllers are not parented and therefore they don't inherit the scale of the master bone.

Comment: do I inherit rotation and location when parenting to master bone as well?

Comment: yes by default but you can disable in the Bone panel > Relations